# Code loses Outlook email template formatting

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I am using this code in MS Access to to open a saved HTML Outlook Template. The code searches for "SALUTATION" in the body of the email and replaces it with controls data from my form.

It works pretty well but, I lose the email formatting which includes formatted text, multiple links and a few images.

How can my code be changed to keep the original formatting?

```
Private Sub Command139_Click()
Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim value As String
    value = Me.Salutation & " " & Me.LastName
        Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MyItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Meiaer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\ELMOVM.oft")
        MyItem.Display
    With MyItem
        .To = Me.EMAIL_ADDRESS
        MyItem.Body = Replace(MyItem.Body, "SALUTATION", value)
   End With
Set MyItem = Nothing
Set myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `MyItem.HTMLBody`, not `MyItem.Body` (which is the plaintext representation of the mail body).

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868941(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: this is what finally foxed it  'MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, "SALUTATION", value)' I tried: 
'MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.Body, "SALUTATION", value)'
and
'MyItem.Body = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, "SALUTATION", value)'

But I never thought to try 'MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, "SALUTATION", value)'